# how to store user name pasword in shared prefrence

Tags: android

how to retrieve data from database using name where name is in form of string but its number  like  name="111000"   thi is a name in string form

```
  String CREATE_USERS_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_USER + "("
    + KEY_USER_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, " + KEY_USER_NAME + " TEXT, " + KEY_USER_PASSWORD + "      
   TEXT " + ")";



         private static final String KEY_USER_ID = "id";
private static final String KEY_USER_NAME = "user_name";
private static final String KEY_USER_PASSWORD = "user_password";

       public String SerchUserName(String UserName) {

    String result = null;


    String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_USER + "  WHERE " +KEY_USER_NAME+ " = '"+String.valueOf(UserName)+"'";
    String result_0;
    String result_1;

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
    // looping through all rows and adding to list

    while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
        result_0 = cursor.getString(0);
        result_1 = cursor.getString(1);
        // and so on
        result = result_0 + "> " + result_1;
    }
    cursor.close();

    db.close();

    return result;

}
```

Comment: String can contain anything. Also, what is the problem with above code? are you not getting expected result? what are you getting? how are you creating your table? what are the columns in your table?

Comment: Your title and question do not ask.

Comment: database retrieve empty value

Answer (score 0):

Your title and question is irrelevant...if you want to know how to store user name pasword in shared prefrence use the below code

i hope it helps

To save user and password in shared preference

```
SharedPreferences preferences = this.getSharedPreferences("com.example.sample.prefs",0);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
editor.putString("USER_NAME","your user name");
editor.putString("PASSWORD","user password");
editor.commit();
```

To retrieve user and password from shared preference

```
SharedPreferences preferences = this.getSharedPreferences("com.example.sample.prefs",0);
String user_name=preferences.getString("USER_NAME",null);
String password=preferences.getString("PASSWORD",null);
```